# Network cable showing unplugged

Tags: windows, windows-xp, internet-connection, ethernet

The network cable is shown to be Unplugged when i connect my ethernet cable to laptop.But when i connect the same cable to my desktop it works fine,why is it so.

Both use Wdows XP OS.

Could it be coz of a damaged port.Until yesterday all was fine.I wonder how suddenly the error appears.

Please help.

Comment: Have you checked that the interface is enabled?

Comment: How to check that?

Comment: I don't have windows XP here so I'm not sure, but somewhere in control panel you have network connections. Right click in the `Loca Area Connection` and check if you can enable it.

Comment: Yeah that is enabled.I have check that earlier.

Comment: Do the link lights on the ethernet port light up when you plug the cable into the laptop?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem that I solved by removing the device and then reinstall it. You can give it a try. Just go to the device manager, search for the NIC, remove it, and then search for new hardware and install it again.

If this doesn't work you can try to use a live CD to make sure the problem is really hardware, and not a Windows problem.

Comment: It has been solved.The laptop now recognizes the connection.It automatically happened to show connection after some while without having to make any amends to settings.

Comment: @techie If that solved it, mark his answer as correct so this question shows as being answered